# PostgreSQL dynamic column selection

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am struggling a bit on some dynamic postgresql :
I have a table named "list_columns" containing the columns names list with "column_name" as the variable name; those column names come from an input table called "input_table".

**[list_columns]**

| **column_name** |
| --- |
| *col_name_a* |
| *col_name_b* |
| *col_name_c...* |

---

**[input_table]**

| **col_name_a** | **col_name_b** | **col_name_c** | **col_name_d** | **col_name_e** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value_a_1 | value_b_1 | value_c_1 | value_d_1 | value_e_1 |
| value_a_2 | value_b_2 | value_c_2 | value_d_2 | value_e_2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

---

What I'd like to do is dynamically create a new table using that list, something like this:

```
create table output_table as
select (select distinct(column_name) seperated by "," from list_columns) from input_table;
```

The resulting table would be
**[output_table]**

| **col_name_a** | **col_name_b** | **col_name_c** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_a_1 | value_b_1 | value_c_1 |
| value_a_2 | value_b_2 | value_c_2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I saw I should use some execute procedures but I can't figure out how to do so.

*Note: I know i could directly select the 3 columns; I oversimplied the case.*

If someone would be kind enough to help me on this,

Thank you,
Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic SQL for this, and for that you need PL/pgSQL.

You need to assemble the `CREATE TABLE` statement based on the `input_table`, then run that generated SQL.

```
do
$$
declare
  l_columns text;
  l_sql text;
begin
  -- this generates the list of columns
  select string_agg(distinct column_name, ',')
    into l_columns
  from list_table;

  -- this generates the actual CREATE TABLE statement using the columns
  -- from the previous step
  l_sql := 'create table output_table as select '||l_columns||' from input_table';

  -- this runs the generated SQL, thus creating the output table.
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$;
```

If you need that a lot, you can put that into a stored function (your unsupported Postgres version doesn't support real procedures).